# Roll up Hierarchical data in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and Scala and trying to figure out how to roll up hierarchical data. The input data map looks like this:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| e1 | e2 |
| e2 | e3 |
| e4 | e2 |
| e5 | e4 |
| e6 | e4 |

I am trying to find a way to roll up the input map into a data frame like below:

| id | level1 | level2 | level3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e1 | e2 | e3 | null |
| e2 | e3 | null | null |
| e3 | null | null | null |
| e4 | e2 | null | null |
| e5 | e4 | e2 | e3 |
| e6 | e4 | e2 | e3 |

I need to use Scala and Spark.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in 3 levels you could perform a left-join twice to achieve this. Initially I have prepared `df1` by using a union to achieve all possible keys and an aggregate to achieve the first level before renaming the columns.

```scala
//rename columns and ensure that all value and keys exist as ids
val df1 = df.union(df.selectExpr("value as key","NULL as value"))
            .groupBy("key")
            .agg(max("value").as("value"))
            .withColumnRenamed("key","id")
            .withColumnRenamed("value","level1")
  


//first repetition for level 2
val level2 = df1.alias("l1").join(
    df1.alias("l2"),
    col("l1.level1")==col("l2.id"),
    "left"
).selectExpr("l1.*","l2.level1 as level2")

//second repetition for level 3
val level3 = level2.alias("l1").join(
    df1.alias("l2"),
    col("l1.level2")==col("l2.id"),
    "left"
).selectExpr("l1.*","l2.level1 as level3")       

level3.show()
```

The example  above was written in such a way which I hope will make it easier to identify a pattern between each repetition. i.e. you could loop to your desired level or depth  using scala eg:

```scala
var df1 = df.union(df.selectExpr("value as key","NULL as value"))
            .groupBy("key")
            .agg(max("value").as("value"))
            .withColumnRenamed("key","id")
            .withColumnRenamed("value","level1")
            .cache()


for( depth <- 1 to 3){
    df1 = df1.alias("l1").join(
              df1.alias("l2"),
              col("l1.level"+depth)==col("l2.id"),
              "left"
          ).selectExpr("l1.*","l2.level"+depth+" as level"+(depth+1))
}

df1.show()
```